# Rails Strong params when attribute can be string or hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a parameter that can be either a string or a hash (metadata) and I would like to allow both using rails strong params

the problem is that metadata can either be a hash or a String or both

```
{transactions: [{metadata: "hello"}, metadata: {name: "world"}]}
```

With the rails params

```
params.permit(:transactions => [:reference_id, :metadata => ["name"]])
```

I have the following error

```
expected Hash (got String) for param `metadata'
```

Comment: `:metadata` perhaps?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo ... editing it now.

Comment: Translate hash to a json data.

Answer (score 0):

I see the only way to permit, is to verify the constant parameters at first, then verify a parameter with variable type:

```
params.permit(:transactions => [:reference_id, :metadata])

begin
   params.permit(:metadata => {})
rescue TypeError
   # here check that :metadata is a string
end
```